# Checkmarks in UITableViewCells showing incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a small scrollable tableView which displays roughly eight rows, when I select a row a checkmark appears, when I select it again it disappears.

The issue is, as I scroll down and the cells are reused, more rows are automatically checked. What is the best practice for tracking which rows require a checkmark so that this does not happen. I have looked everywhere but haven't found Swift solution that works well.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(searchResults.usernameUserSearchArray[indexPath.row])"

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if selectedCell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark {

        selectedCell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

    } else {

        selectedCell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Do you want only one cell to be checked at the same time?

Comment: Thanks, I need to be able to select multiple cells

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wouldn't something like this do it for you? I haven't tested it since I am not on my Mac.

```
var selectedCells = [NSIndexPath]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!
    cell.accessoryType = selectedCells.contains(indexPath) ? .Checkmark : .None

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    selectedCells.append(indexPath)

    if selectedCell?.accessoryType == .Checkmark {

        selectedCell?.accessoryType = .None

        selectedCells = selectedCells.filter {$0 != indexPath}

    } else {

        selectedCell?.accessoryType = .Checkmark
    }
}
```

Comment: @LuckyLuke Dont you think the code of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` has a bug. It will append in the array whether you select or deselect.
Its better to remove items in `didDeSelectRowAtIndexPath` and also we can use Set rather than an array because of possible duplication.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari Removing items in didDeSelect would have also removed the checkmark every time a new row is selected. I have updated the remove function as the previous version wasn't removing the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` create an NSMutableArray which stores selected index of the cell and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check using if condition from array whether index path is available in array or not. If available than set accessory type checkmark true for index path.

Comment: I have been trying something along these lines to no avail. Sorry to ask but are you able to post example code?

Comment: Use set rather than array as it will not duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = arr.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
    if(arr .objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String  == selectedValue.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String)
    {
       cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if selectedCell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark {

        selectedCell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        selectedValue .removeObject(arr .objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))

    } else {

        selectedCell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        selectedValue .addObject(arr .objectAtIndex(indexPath.row))
    }


}
```

Comment: This should be added to your previous answer instead of creating a new answer.