# switch change on tableview row affecting other rows

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch, valuechangelistener

I have the following class for a table view cell:

```
class QuestionCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var questionAnswer: UISwitch!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    var data: Answer?

    func configureForQuestion(data: Answer) {
        print("configureForQuestion triggered")
        questionLabel.text = data.question
        self.data = data
    }

    @IBAction func questionAnswerChanged(sender: UISwitch) {
        data?.answer = sender.on
    }
}
```

This cell consists of a label and switch. Currently when I change the switch status for the first row, it is also changing for the last row. No other rows seem to be connected in this way. I'm pretty stumped  on this one.

Extra info:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return answers.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(TableView.CellIdentifiers.QuestionCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuestionCell
    cell.configureForQuestion(answers[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Comment: this is the hint, tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier() the dequedCells are creating the problem.

Comment: @satheeshwaran so thow could i get around this?

Comment: So if you toggle switch in row 2 is it affecting anything else or it just happens with row 1 always??

Comment: I have had a similar issue which was solved by tracking the relevant cells in an array. Have a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369939/checkmarks-in-uitableviewcells-showing-incorrectly

Comment: @satheeshwaran just row 1 affecting the last row always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override prepareForReuse in the cell and reset you ui elements data.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.questionLabel.text = nil
    self.questionAnswer.on = data?.answer
}
```

Comment: originally I had questionAnswer.on = false in my configureForQuestion func, but that was causing an issue in that if i turned a switch on and scrolled down the tableview and back up, the switch would be reset to false :(

Comment: fixed it - needed to put questionAnswer.on = data.answer into my configureForQuestion func!

Comment: nice! approved answer?

Comment: I could approve it if you changed it! self.questionAnswer.on = false is wrong as it was resetting turned on switches to false when they were scrolled out of view and reloaded after

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your `answers` array does not have the data you expect. Print out the values of `answers` in the debugger and see if each `answer` has the `indexPath.row` you expect it to have.

Can you show your code for how you set the values in `answers`?